# Serial Port communication in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, activex

I have a legacy application which is making use of `ActiveX` control for serial communication. This is rightly communicating in IE.

Since ActiveX is IE specific technology obviously it will not run in Chrome or other browser

So I don't want to disturb the IE functionality and thought of introducing browser specific function as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

 var isIEBrowserFlag = true;
 if(isIEBrowserFlag)
 {
  var obj = new ActiveXObject("MSCommLib.MSComm");
  obj.CommPort = commPort;
  obj.RThreshold = thresHold;
  obj.Settings = settings;
  obj.PortOpen = true;
  obj.DTREnable = true;
  obj.Output = "test";
 obj.PortOpen = false;

//other stuff
 }
 else
 {
    //chrome
 }
 //sendBagToPrinter(obj);
});
```

On googling I came to know about `jQuery.parseXML()` but how do I implement the same functionality as of IE in Chrome using  $.parseXML()

Similar other plugins such as `juart` were tried, but not fitting my requirement.

Comment: Serial Port communication has nothing to do with jQuery.parseXML().

Answer (score 0):

chrome.serial API provides access to client serial ports, but from a Chrome App.
My suggestion, for future support, use/write some kind of server for serial device and connect from browser to server via a json type communication. See https://github.com/johnlauer/serial-port-json-server